# SQLite change command line prompt to nothing

Tags: sqlite

I can use `.prompt prompt` to change prompt of command line interface of sqlite3.

How can I set normal prompt and continuation prompt to nothing? empty string or newline would be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.prompt` changes both prompts (main and continuation) simultaneously, they must be divided by space `.prompt mainprompt continuationprompt`

In my particular case I need `.prompt "" ""`

Answer (score 2):

Just use quotes.

Try `prompt ""`.